# multiline input reading input from stdin in C

Tags: c, line, stdin

Hello every one I want to ask that is there a way in c programming through which I can read multi line input from stdin

as I cant use scanf() also not fgets as it take input till /n

and also how to stop the input like some delimiter

thanks alot

also I am not using c++

Answer (score 1):

Use [`fread`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html).

eg, *copied from the link*

```
#include <stdio.h>
...
size_t bytes_read;
char buf[100];
FILE *fp;
...
bytes_read = fread(buf, sizeof(buf), 1, fp);
...
```

Comment: This might actually be the fastest if the OP scans for the delimiter himself.

Comment: `fread` won't work well if you want to read unknown number of characters from a stream.

Comment: @Banthar: actually it works very well under those circumstances. It's very easy to write a file copy program using `fread` (and `fwrite`). Such a program copies single-byte files as well as several megabyte ones.

Comment: @pmg Yes, but it's very hard to write a program that reads everything until some character and nothing more. Which is what you want in interactive programs.

Comment: Ah! I agree with you, @Banthar. I didn't quite get what you meant before. For your information, [Zack's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717643/multiline-input-reading-input-from-stdin-in-c/7717700#7717700) (with `getc`) was upvoted by me.

Comment: Of course, `getc` won't do the job if you need to stop reading _from the operating system_ when you hit a delimiter, because stdio has buffers.  I'm not aware of any way to do _that_ other than `read` one character at a time, inefficient as that is.  (Well, you can disable stdio's buffering, but that's equivalent.)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you read input one character at a time with `getc`, look for whatever delimiter you want, and append the non-delimiter characters to a buffer whose size you control manually (with `realloc`).  The alternative is to read large blocks with `fread` and scan for the delimiters, but the `getc` approach is likely to be easier and simpler.

Make sure to look for `EOF` as well as your explicit delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

This task would be pretty simple if there were a proper string datatype in C, with automatic memory management. The idea is:

```
string s = str_new();
const char *delimiter = "EOF\n";
while (true) {
  int c = fgetc(f);
  if (c == EOF) {
    break;
  }
  str_appendc(s, c);
  if (str_endswith(s, delimiter)) {
    str_setlen(s, str_len(s) - strlen(delimiter));
    break;
  }
}
```

You just have to write the proper functions for the string handling.